# How to get a datetime value within a string?

Tags: c#

I've got a string that contains a value of `datetime`:

```
string myStr = "= '2015-12-01 00:00:00.000'";
```

How can I check if `myStr` contains a `datetime` value?

How can I get only the `datetime` value from `myStr`? The `datetime` value got from `myStr` should be: `"2015-12-01 00:00:00.000"`.

---

The sample code that I have tried to do the task:

```
string myStr = "= '2015-12-01 00:00:00.000'";    
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}");
Match mat = rgx.Match(myStr);
if (mat.ToString() != "") //This will check if string contains datetime value
{
     DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse(mat.ToString()); //This will get the datetime value from string
}
```

*Note: The result from the sample code above is: It can't check if myStr contains a datetime value. It can't get the datetime value from `myStr`.*

---

**You could help me to check if a string contains a datetime value, and get the datetime value within a string.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var myStr = "= '2015-12-01 00:00:00.000'";
var match = Regex.Matches(myStr, @"'(.*?)'")[0].Groups[1].Value;

DateTime result;
if (DateTime.TryParse(match.ToString(), out result)) {
    // Your string has a valid DateTime and it is parsed in result
}
else {
   // Invalid
}
```

Comment: Your code can get the datetime value from my string. But when you parse, it gave a result of "{01/01/0001 00:00:00}"

Comment: @Trind07 I get `12/1/2015 12:00:00 AM` as output. See a [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YVBgs5)

Comment: One thing I should let you know. If your code run to line var match = Regex.Matches(myStr, @"'(.*?)'")[0].Groups[1].Value;  and if myStr has no datetime value, it will generate an exception.

Comment: @Trind07 It may probably give an `IndexOutOfRangeException`, I assumed the string as is.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things we need to do:

1. Write a regex which get things that *look* like they might be a date. However, since dates can be exceedingly complex, we want to delegate that validation to the built-in `DateTime` library.
2. For each possible match, we want to validate that it's actually a date.

```
private IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDates(string str)
{
    var dateSearcherRegex = new Regex(@"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}");

    foreach (Match match in dateSearcherRegex.Matches(str))
    {
        var matchedString = match.Groups[0].Value;
        DateTime date;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(matchedString, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
        {
            yield return date;
        }
    }
}
```

And using it like this:

```
string myStr = "= '2015-12-01 00:00:00.000'";

var dates = GetDates(myStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string myStr = "= '2015-12-01 00:00:00.000'";
 DateTime dt;
 bool b = DateTime.TryParse(myStr.Split(' ')[1].Replace("'",string.Empty),out dt);
     if (b)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("contains datetime");
     }
     else
     {
          Console.WriteLine("doesn't contain datetime");
     }
```

Use TryParse function to check for DateTime values

Comment: Your code is correct when checking a datetime within a string. But how can I get only datetime value from the string?

Comment: datetime value is in dt variable

Comment: Yes it is in dt variable, but it's got only date but not time. Result:
From "= '2015-12-31 23:59:59.000'" to {31/12/2015 00:00:00}

Comment: dt.Hour, dt.Minute and dt.Minute will give you time. In current string all are zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want using regex to parse the date:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}");
Match result = rgx.Match(myStr);

if (mat.Success)
{
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(m.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

CMIIW.